# Specifying First Appearance in Regex

Tags: regex, string

I am writing some Regex codes. How can I only search for the first instance 
that the string appears in the text. For example, if I want to search for the first
number that appears in a text(I don't care about other numbers and I don't want
them highlighted), how do I specify that in Regex?

I am writing raw Regex code and testing them on online testers such as 
Rubular.com and regexpal.com .

Comment: this isn't possible to answer without telling us which language/editor etc you're using with this regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how regex works by default, you usually have to provide a global option or use a specific function to find all matches.

So, if you were to use the regex `\d+` to look for one or more digits, the regex engine would only match up to the first group of digits (first number).

Note that this may not be the case if you are using an online tool or text editor instead of a programming language, so if this doesn't help please specify how you are performing your regex search.

You could use the following regex to get the first number in the first capture group and not match anything else:

```
^[^\d]*(\d+)
```

Explanation:

```
^         # start of string
[^\d]*    # match zero or more non-digit characters
(\d+)     # match one or more digits and place them in the first capture group
```

Comment: What are you using for your testing?  For example in Python, `re.search(r'\d+', s)` would find the first number in the string `s`.  If you are using an online tool or a text editor, it is probably implicitly doing a global search.  See the following  link for an example: http://regexr.com?31v8t (note how this changes when you click the `global` checkbox)

Comment: Online tools like that will often find all matches without giving you an option to search only for the first match, but only finding the first match is the default behavior for most (if not all) regex implementations in programming languages.  If you are not planning on adapting your regex to a programming language and you are just using the online tools to see how they work, you could use `^[^\d]*(\d+)` to get the first number in the first capture group and not match anything else.

Comment: @GTyler Edited my answer with an explanation for the regex from my comment.

Answer (score 0):

[Most Regex tools, which use regex-directed engines, always return the leftmost match.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html)

> The Regex-Directed Engine Always Returns the Leftmost Match because
>   the engine is "eager" to report a match. The engine never proceeds
>   beyond this point to see if there are any "better" matches. The first
>   match is considered good enough.

But tools that use the regex engine (like Notepad++, EditPad, and millions of others) have it configured that it should highlight all matches. (which makes sense for text editors) (This also is true for most online regex testers).

To resolve your issue, if you are using a Regex library like the .NET Regex library, you can use [Regex.Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx) to get the first matched occurence.
For e.g, in C#:

```
string regexPattern = "\d";
string inputText = @"Ka3jf7we8ewdv"; 
Regex r = new Regex(regexPattern);
Match m = r.Match(inputText);
Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
```

Comment: `m.Groups[1].Value` makes no sense because there are no capturing groups in your regex.  You want the whole match, which is just `m.Value`.

Comment: You are right.. I jumped the gun using a previous example I had. Fixed it.